# How do I get end time of an Event in eventDrop-function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I´ve got a question about fullcalendar.

I´d like to get the end-date of an event when it´s dropped to another position. But the following code only displays null in alert. Can somebody help me? The format should be yyyy-mm-dd. Thanks!

```
eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
            alert(event.end);
           saveDrop(event, event.end);
},
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(event);`, it should list all the event properties and end should be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to post whole calendar setting. I used your alert code from eventDrop event and i received info about event.end date after moving it in the calendar.

i added following formatted alert with end date of event:

```
alert($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

which display date in YYYY-MM-DD format. 
For date formatting is used [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

or [fullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/)